# How to remove double quotes from queries in Apache Drill generated from SAP HANA Smart data access?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hana, apache-drill, mapr

I have a few hive table, I am trying to access in **HANA** using smart data access virtual tables. I am using **MapR drill odbc driver** and setup the dsn accordingly. Now I am able to refresh my remote source, create virtual tables. But when I am trying to query the virtual tables, it errors out. After analyzing the queries that reaching Drill, I noticed the schema name is enclosed in double-quotes, which is causing the issue.

```
e.g. Select * from "hive.schma".table1;
```

I am trying setting the quoting_identifier = ", which helps me to query already created Virtual tables but I lose the schema refresh functionality and virtual table create capability.

I am using: `HANA 1 SPS 12, Drill 1.16.0.0, MapR distribution`.

Answer (score 0):

The two quote characters that have had substantial runtime in Drill are the back-quote and the square brackets. Using double quotes runs the danger of collision with other meanings, obviously including the quoting of strings.

The best way to get an authoritative answer on this is to ask on the Calcite user mailing list or the Drill user mailing list. Few of the main contributors look for questions here on stack overflow.

If you are a MapR customer, you can also ping the MapR support team via your normal channels.